# Is it possible to perform Inner Join with Lookup Multiple Value Field?

Tags: list, caml-query, caml, multiple-values

I use CAML Query to perform **inner join** between two lists. It works when the `lookup` field is **single value**. However, when this field is **multiple value**, it always throws error:

> the value does not fall within the expected range

I just wonder that Does SharePoint support this kind of query with lookup multiple value field? If so, what is the correct syntax?

Are there any alternatives to perform such kind of query?

This is the caml query. Anyway, when I edit the lookup field to allow single value, then it works. So, it must be due to the type of lookup field.

```
query.Joins = "<Join Type='INNER' ListAlias='Cat'>" +
              "<Eq>" +
                  "<FieldRef Name='Category' RefType='ID'/>" +
                  "<FieldRef List='Category' Name='ID'/>" +
              "</Eq>" +
         "</Join>";

query.ProjectedFields = "<Field Name='CatTitle' Type='Lookup' List='Category' ShowField='Title'/>";
```

Comment: Please mention the error that you are getting

Comment: can you share the Kaml query ?